# Calling a Key in a dictionary using a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, variables

I am trying to be able to return the budget number for a specific dictionary based on a user defined variable. I am not having any luck figuring this out on my own, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
owners = ['rob','andre']
team_balance = {}

for name in owners:
    team_balance[name.capitalize()] ={'budget':200}

x='Rob' # x will be user defined using input()

print(team_balance[{x}]['budget'])
```

Trying the above results in the follwing error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I can see two errors where I can't tell what you really mean. Did you mean to print: `team_balance['ROB']['budget']`? Or: `team_balance[x.capitalize()]['budget']`?

Comment: @quamrana Rob is a temporary, as they say in the comment. `# x will be user defined using input()`.

Comment: Do `team_balance[x]['budget']`. You're getting the error because of the `{ }`, which you don't need. It seems to me you  might be confusing this  with  `f`-strings. This would also work: `team_balance[f"{x}"]['budget']`, but it would be an unnecessarily complicated way to do something very straightforward.

Comment: *print(team_balance[x.capitalize()]['budget'])* although take care with user input and consider what could happen if the given name (*x*) isn't in the dictionary

Comment: @LancelotduLac: Yes, that's the next step after the OP explains what they want to achieve.

Comment: @quamrana What he wants to achieve is implied by the last line of code which is where the stated error occurs. Also, the first sentence of the description begins "I am trying to be able to return the budget number..."

Comment: @quamrana I am looking to print team_balance[x.capitalize()]['budget'] ultimately. So, if user says 'rob' on the input, it will match with the 'Rob' key.

Comment: There is no `"Rob"` key by definition.

Comment: @BoarGules PERFECT!! Thank you so much, i was indeed confusing with the f-string variables. just using [x] worked!

Comment: @quamrana What do you think 'rob'.capitalize() will generate?

Comment: So, now, can we ask what you want to happen if the user inputs a key that is missing?

Comment: @LancelotduLac: Oh, sorry, my bad. I saw `capitalize()` and was thinking: `upper()`!

Comment: @LancelotduLac I would like an error message saying something along the lines of 'owner does not exist'. I planned on using an if statement with not .isin(owners) then printing the error, else print the budget dollars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to leave out the curly braces like so:

```
print(team_balance[x]['budget'])
```

If you add them, the result is a set, which you can check like that:

```
isinstance({x}, set)
```

A set can't be used as a dictionary key, because it is unhashable (which pretty much means it can be changed).

Answer (score 2):

```
owners = ['rob','andre']
team_balance = {}

for name in owners:
    team_balance[name.capitalize()] ={'budget':200}

x=input() # user will enter this value
```

Use try except to handle exception

```
try:
  print(team_balance[x.capitalize()]['budget']) 
except:
  print("Entered value not in owners list ")
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from the '{}' in the last line.

When you defined your dictionary, you used strings as keys. So you have to use strings when you call a value from the dictionary.

`x='Rob'` also assigns a string in `x`, so is it good as it is.
We can use the function `type` to check the class of an object :

```
>>> type(x)
<class 'str'>
```

What's wrong with the last line is the `{x}` that transform you string into a set of string. A set is like a list but unordered, unchangeable and with only uniques values.

```
>>> type({x})
<class 'set'>
```

So as you're not using the same type of object to get than the one you use to set the values, it can't work.

The error message you get

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

is because a set object is unhasable, so it can't be used as a dictionary key (it is explained why [here](https://thepythoncorner.com/posts/2020-08-21-hash-tables-understanding-dictionaries/)). But even if a set would have been a hashable object, you wouldn't have the value you wanted as it is not equal to what you used to define the keys.

Just remove the `{}` :

```
owners = ['rob','andre']
team_balance = {}

for name in owners:
    team_balance[name.capitalize()] ={'budget':200}

x='Rob' # x will be user defined using input()

print(team_balance[x]['budget'])


>>> 200
```